# $ is not defined Laravel 5.8

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

This got me so confused, I am not using the `layouts.app` of `make:auth`.

Here's my `head` tag of my **layouts.master**

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>ZIAN PAYROLL SYSTEM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/custom.css')}}">

 </head>
```

and here's my script:

```
<script>
    $('#promote').on('show.bs.modal', function(event){
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
        var name = button.data('myname')
        var id = button.data('myid')
        var modal = $(this)

        console.log(id);
        modal.find('.modal-body #myname').val(name);
        modal.find('.modal-body #myid').val(id);
    })  
</script>
```

Followed some steps here in stack yet nothing helped. I know that removing the `defer` in the script would work but mine wouldn't.

Comment: That usually means that jQuery isn't loaded (or wasn't loaded before your script). Is it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You should add the jQuery library in your document. For example:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>ZIAN PAYROLL SYSTEM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/custom.css')}}">

 </head>
```